# Access VBA find value for loading website

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to open the DB, find the row with site value that the user chooses and then get the JobRef as text. So far I am lost for ideas as to how to achieve this.

I have this so far:

```
    Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT tProjects.JobRef FROM tProjects WHERE tProjects.Site = '" + Combo2.Value + "'"
Set jref = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
```

But all this does is open the data, and when using jref.value I get a type mismatch.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: pls share your table details and error u r getting

Comment: How did you define jref ?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, it just cannot be used as text for an input into another string.
I have not specifically defined jref, what should it be?

Comment: it will be jref.fields(0).value I believe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx   returns a https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197799.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Add it as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: you can just do : `Dim JobRef As String` and not use jref at all. Then instead of Set jref, just write `JobRef =  CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL).fields(0).value` as Nathan said